SQL unique constraint on multiple columns
I am trying to figure out a cross unique constraint on 2 columns, I know how to do 2 columns, but not cross columns
here is a sample of my data



Connection
Dealer1
Dealer2




1
10
20


2
20
30


3
20
10



my application considers connection 1 & 3 a duplicate as they both have the same dealers. is there any way to setup a constraint to do this?
these are my constraints so far
ALTER TABLE DealerConnections ADD CONSTRAINT UC_DealerConnections_Dealer1 UNIQUE (Dealer1FK,Dealer2FK)
ALTER TABLE DealerConnections ADD CONSTRAINT UC_DealerConnections_Dealer2 UNIQUE (Dealer2FK,Dealer1FK)

all three connections pass the constraints, but i want connection 3 to fail as it duplicates 1

What's the database?

-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE DealerConnections (
    ConnectionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Dealer1FK INT NOT NULL,
    Dealer2FK INT NOT NULL
);

-- Add the computed column
ALTER TABLE DealerConnections
ADD ComputedDealerPair AS 
    (CASE 
        WHEN Dealer1FK < Dealer2FK THEN CAST(Dealer1FK AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(Dealer2FK AS VARCHAR)
        ELSE CAST(Dealer2FK AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(Dealer1FK AS VARCHAR)
    END);

-- Create the unique index on the computed column
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_UniqueDealerPair
ON DealerConnections (ComputedDealerPair);


Conceptually it's better to add a unique constraint to the generated column rather than just a unique index.

@TheImpaler But in practice unique indexes are more useful as they can have INCLUDEs and WHERE, and FKs can still target them. The big concern here is the concatenation: there is no reason why there couldnt have just been two separate computed columns, and keep the data type. Also varchar without a length = Very Bad.

@Charlieface Yes, two columns are preferrable, especially when converting to VARCHAR is not trivial. Now, indexes are more flexible as well, but I personally see constraints as more conceptually correct; performance is another subject to consider as well, of course.
